# Signalr self host server working with Console app not in WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, console, signalr

I am developing Signalr self host server application with javascript client. It working with Console app but same code not working with in WPF.

Here is my console app code.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {                
            string url = "http://localhost:8080";
            using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
    class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
    public class MyHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            Clients.All.addMessage(name, message);
        }
    }
```

And WPF code.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string url = "http://localhost:8080";
            using (WebApp.Start(url))
            {                   
            }
        }
    }
    class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
    public class MyHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            Clients.All.addMessage(name, message);
        }
    }
```

And in javascirpt access it following way

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () { 
            $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:8080/signalr";

            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
            var chat = $.connection.myHub;
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                chat.server.send('test', 'message');
            });
       });
</script>
```

Now when run console app it's working perfect. it sending message and also i got hit on debug point on Send method. But when run with WPF app, in browser console i get following javascirpt error

> "Error loading hubs. Ensure your hubs reference is correct"

Any one have idea why it is not working with WPF application?

.

Comment: is it okay that you are using non-generic method `WebApp.Start` in WPF application?

Comment: I had also tried generic method but still not success